# JSON_Encode returns NULL (Array)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to parse JSONresponse in Android Studio, and just realized that JSON_Encode returns NULL. Any ideas what could cause this? I am using PHP 5.2.X

Here is my php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $con = mysqli_connect("myhost", "myuser", "mypass", "a5911579_android");

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM markers    ORDER BY marker_id");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $arrRows = array();
    $arryItem = array();
    $arrRows["success"] = false;
    $arryItem["success"] = false;

    while($arr = mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $arryItem["marker_id"] = $arr["marker_id"];
        $arryItem["lat"] = $arr["lat"];
        $arryItem["lng"] = $arr["lng"];
        $arryItem["snippet"] = $arr["snippet"];
        $arrRows[] = $arryItem;
    }

    echo json_encode($arrRows);
?>
```

This is my response:

> {"success":false,"0":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"1":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"2":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"3":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"4":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"5":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"6":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null}}

It returns null for both lat, lng, snippet and even marker_id, even though there are values for those in my database (using mysql).

Any help is much appreciated!

Update: inserted $arr, but still getting same result
Update: using

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($marker_id,$lat,$lng,$snippet);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
$arrRows[] = compact('marker_id','lat','lng','snippet');
}
```

gives this error (still null returned):

```
<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in <b>/home/a5911579/public_html/GetAuction2.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'>     <font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>
```

> {"success":false,"0":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"1":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"2":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"3":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"4":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"5":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"6":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null}}

Comment: Where's `$arr` defined? Maybe you meant to do `while ($arr = mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {` ?

Comment: @apokryfos You're correct, still getting the same results though

Comment: (1) you need to increase your error reporting level when developing to catch these sort of problems (2) can you do a `print_r($arr)` to make sure it does indeed have the data you expect?

Comment: Off topic, but PHP 5.2 has been obsolete and totally unsupported for many years now. It has multiple known severe security flaws. If you're still using it on a public-facing web server, you are crazy. You need to be planning an upgrade urgently.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `mysqli_stmt_bind_result(...);` for binding value in listed variables. you can use `compact()` for make array from variable name

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($marker_id,$lat,$lng,$snippet);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $arrRows[] = compact('marker_id','lat','lng','snippet');
}
```

Comment: `$arr =` is probably no longer needed in the while-statement

Comment: This gives me a whole bunch of other errors (remember i am using php 5.2). However ultimately returns null aswell (will update question with result)